# GET rest api fails at client side

Tags: rest, web

Suppose client call server using GET API, is it possible that server send a response but client misses that response??

If yes how to handle such situation, as I want to make sure that client receives the data. For now I am using second REST call by client as ack of first.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. For example if you are using a site with a REST API and a request is just sent to the API and your internet connection dies when the answer is supposed to arrive, then it is quite possible that the server has received your request, successfully handled it, even sent the response, but your computer did not receive it. It could be an issue on a server responsible for transmitting the request as well. The solution to this kind of issue is to have a timeout and if a request timed out, then resend it until it is no longer timed out.